# Updating Parent Form Textboxes from Child Form Datagridview Selected Row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Parent Form QuotationDetails in which I have a button called ChooseCustomer and when I click it a child form named CustomerSearchForm is opened.Now there is a Datagridview CustomerSearchForm with two button OK and CANCEL.So when I select a Row from the DGV and Click OK all the details from that row are filled in the QuotationDetails (around 20 Textboxes) with the selected customer Customer data.I have written all the code and its working fine.But the problem is I am doing this by closing the Parent form QuotationDetails and opening a new instance of it.But the requirement is I need to display the Parent form and update the Textboxes from Childform.

Below is the Code for Loading Customer Details from ChildForm

```
public void btnLoadCustomerDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QuotationManagement objQM = new QuotationManagement();
           string[] Details = new string[gvCustomerDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells.Count];
            for (int i = 1; i < gvCustomerDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                Details[i] = gvCustomerDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
            }
            objQM.txtCustomerdetails.Text = Details[3] + Environment.NewLine + Details[4] + "," + Details[5] + "," + Details[6] + "," + Details[7];
            objQM.txtcustContact.Text = Details[3];
            objQM.txtCustPhoneno.Text = Details[10];
            objQM.txtfaxNo.Text = Details[12];
            objQM.txtCustMobile.Text = Details[15];
            objQM.txtcustemail.Text = Details[14];
            objQM.txtCustWeb.Text = Details[16];
            objQM.txtcustsource.Text = Details[29];
            objQM.txtCustActivestatus.Text = Details[27];
            objQM.txtCustomerType.Text = Details[44];
            objQM.txtCustNomAccType.Text = "Customer Quotations";
            objQM.txtCustAccStatus.Text = Details[25];
            objQM.txtTerms.Text = Details[31];
            objQM.txtCurrency.Text = Details[33];
            objQM.txtcountryname.Text = Details[9];
            objQM.lblCustomermasterId.Text = Details[0];
            this.Close();
            objQM.tabQuotationManagement.SelectedIndex = 1;
            objQM.Show();            

        }
```

I have searched for a solution and got an Idea to use Event and a Delegate to trigger it.

But I am not sure how to implement the same in my scenario.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this winforms? asp.net? o what?

Comment: Datagridview..quite obvious its a Winform

Comment: quite obvious you should properly tag your questions.

Comment: I have tagged it to C# and Datagridview..forgot to tag it to Winforms..done it

Comment: Have you passed a reference to your parent form into the child form?

Comment: hi Charles...My idea is to send the selected DataGridviewRow to the Parent Form from the ChildFrom button Click event.So that I can get data from the row.But no idea on how o create the event for the same.

Comment: So, I would suggest not closing your parent form and using Showdialog on the child form.  This puts it as the top window and needs to be dismissed before control goes back to your main form.  With that in mind, I would then suggest either creating a class to hold the results or some variables in your child form.  When showdialog returns you can then query the child form for the class/variables that hold the data and populate the main form as needed.

Comment: Creating Variables is a simple way to implement my requirement.But the problem is Parent form contains more than 30 Textboxes.So creating variables is not that Idea.ShowDialog part I had already implemented it.I am not sure but sending the selected DatagridviewROw to the Parent form and then updating the textboxes from the row is a better idea.My searching for a code snipped to implement my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the child form returning the selected Gridview row.

****Main Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //call the form
            MyChildForm cForm = new MyChildForm();
            if (cForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {   //get the selected row object
                DataGridViewRow dgvRow = cForm.selectedRow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

****Child Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class MyChildForm : Form
    {
        public DataGridViewRow selectedRow;

        public MyChildForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyChildForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Forms closing so lets get the results
            selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have used constructor method to implement my requirement as shared above.But using that a new instance of form is created. I mean After I click the button for searching customer details, Quotation Details form is still open and i need that.After selecting the customer and clicked on OK button in CustomerForm a new instance of Quotation Details form is opened while the already opened form is still existing i.e two instances of Quotation Details form are opened.Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.Below is the code I have implemented using a constructor.

Code for CustomerSearch OK button

```
public void btnLoadCustomerDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
selectedRow = gvCustomerDetails.SelectedRows[0];
QuotationManagement objQM = new QuotationManagement(selectedRow);
objQM.tabQuotationManagement.SelectedIndex = 1;
objQM.Show();
this.Close();


}
```

Code for QuotationDetails form to load the CustomerDetails

```
public QuotationManagement(DataGridViewRow SelectedRow)
{
InitializeComponent();
CusRow = SelectedRow;
LoadSelectedCustomerDetails(CusRow);

}


private void LoadSelectedCustomerDetails(DataGridViewRow CusRow)
{
txtCustomerdetails.Text = CusRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + CusRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "," + CusRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "," + CusRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "," + CusRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
txtcustContact.Text = CusRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
txtCustPhoneno.Text = CusRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
txtfaxNo.Text = CusRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
txtCustMobile.Text = CusRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
txtcustemail.Text = CusRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
txtCustWeb.Text = CusRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
txtcustsource.Text = CusRow.Cells[29].Value.ToString();
txtCustActivestatus.Text = CusRow.Cells[27].Value.ToString();
txtCustomerType.Text = CusRow.Cells[44].Value.ToString();
txtCustNomAccType.Text = "Customer Quotations";
txtCustAccStatus.Text = CusRow.Cells[25].Value.ToString();
txtTerms.Text = CusRow.Cells[31].Value.ToString();
txtCurrency.Text = CusRow.Cells[33].Value.ToString();
txtcountryname.Text = CusRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
lblCustomermasterId.Text = CusRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();     

}
```

Apart from loading the textboxes in Quotation form with the CustomerDetails. There are other additional textboxes where user can do manual entry.But when the user enters the data and then selects the customer data all the data in textboxes(manually entered) is lost. The reason is we are loading the form again.I can use Static to store the entered data.Apart from that is there any better way to do the same.